# Specs for controller inside a module (versionist)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, module

I'm creating an API in Rails and I use [versionist](https://github.com/bploetz/versionist) to handle versions. I want to test API controllers, but I'm unable to create a valid request.

My controller:

```
 class Api::V1::ItemsController < Api::V1::BaseController    
  def index
    render json:'anything'
  end
end
```

My spec:

```
describe Api::V1::ItemsController do
  describe "#create" do
    it "shows items" do
      get :index, format: :json
    end
  end
end
```

routes.rb:

```
scope '/api' do
  api_version(:module => "Api::V1", :path => {:value => "v1"}, :default => true) do
    resources :items
  end
end
```

The test doesn't check anything. Still, it raises an error:

```
 Failure/Error: get :index, format: :json
 ActionController::RoutingError:
   No route matches {:format=>:json, :controller=>"api/v1/items", :action=>"index"}
```

I suppose that there is something wrong with the `:controller` key in the request, but I don't know how to fix it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this locally. You need to move this to a request spec instead of a controller spec for this to work:

```
# spec/requests/api/v1/items_controller_spec.rb
describe Api::V1::ItemsController do
  describe "#index" do
    it "shows items" do
      get '/api/v1/items.json'
      # assert something
    end
  end
end
```

The versionist documentation says you need to do this when using the HTTP header or request parameter versioning strategies (https://github.com/bploetz/versionist#a-note-about-testing-when-using-the-http-header-or-request-parameter-strategies) but that's clearly not the case here. I'll file an issue to get this clarified in the documentation that you need to do this for *all* versioning strategies.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was about to give up  versionist, but with such a support I'll keep using it ;-).

Comment: By the way, you should report these types of issues on the versionist Github page, not here. I just happened to see this post by chance. :-)

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure if it's versionist issue or my fault :) (you might have noticed that the old title didn't mention versionist).