# gem versionist(path strategy) test rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec2

There is a method "sign_up" in controller

```
# controller/v3/users_controller
# POST api/v3/users/sign_up
def sign_up    
  user = User.new(params[:user])
  if user.save && user.update_attribute(:channel, "user_#{user.id}")
    render json: { Auth: { message: t(:sign_up_ok), user_id: user.id, channel: user.channel } }, status: 201
  else
    render json: { errors: Oj.load(user.errors.to_json) }, status: 400
  end
end
```

route.rb

```
api_version(module: 'V3', path: 'api/v3') do
  resources :users, only: [:index, :show, :destroy] do
    collection do
    post 'sign_up'
    post 'sign_in'
  end
end
```

I am trying to test it:

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe V3::UsersController do
  describe "POST 'sign_up'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      post '/api/v3/users/sign_up'
      assert_response 200
    end
  end
end
```

Get an error:

```
V3::UsersController POST 'sign_up' should be successful
  Failure/Error: post '/api/v3/users/sign_up'
  ActionController::RoutingError:
    No route matches {:controller=>"v3/users", :action=>"/api/v3/users/sign_up"}
 # ./spec/controllers/v3/user_controller_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

rake routes

```
sign_up_api_v3_users POST    /api/v3/users/sign_up(.:format)     V3/users#sign_up
```

Please, give me advice how to test this method?

ruby-1.9.3
rails-3.2.12

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14586573/specs-for-controller-inside-a-module-versionist/14593358#14593358

Is your spec a controller spec or a request spec?

Comment: Oh thanks. I moved this to a request spec and it worked

Answer (score 0):

The action is not supposed to include the full path, just the name of the action.

```
post :sign_up
```

RSpec infers the rest of the path based on the controller your using. As you can see in the error message, it figured out the controller was v3/users, and it took your action, which is not a valid action.

Comment: i used gem versionist. I send the following request: localhost:3000/api/v3/users/sign_up 
If i use post :sign_up get the same error: No route matches {:controller=>"v3/users", :action=>"sign_up"}

Comment: I'm not sure then, I do know that rspec controller specs don't take a path as they do not go through the middleware stack like request specs. Are you missing some required params?

Comment: No, even when I send get request to the index, I get the same error